# Calculating Mutual Information with Binning (histograms) in R

Tags: r

I have the following codes with two functions to calculate the mutual information of variables `x` and `y` using binning method.

```
entropy <- function(p) {
  if (sum(p) == 0) {
    return(0) 
  }
  p <- p/sum(p) 
  p <- p[p > 0] 
  H = -sum(p*log(p,base=2))
  return(H)
}

mutual.info <- function(counts) {

  marginal.entropy = entropy(rowSums(counts))
  probs <- colSums(counts)/sum(counts)
  column.entropies = apply(counts,2,entropy)
  conditional.entropy = sum(probs*column.entropies)
  mutual.information = marginal.entropy - conditional.entropy
  return(mutual.information)
}

x=c(0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0)
y=c(0.8,1.0,0.6,0.4,0.0,0.2)

xc<-quantile(x,(0:3)/3)
yc<-quantile(y,(0:3)/3)

xbin<-summary(cut(x,xc,include.lowest=TRUE))
ybin<-summary(cut(y,yc,include.lowest=TRUE))

mi <- as.matrix(cbind(xbin,ybin))

mutual.info(mi)
```

Please I want some one to help me find the problem in calculating mutual information of the above code, it always gives me zero but the answer is ~ 1.58 using the bins = 3.

Thank you,

Comment: What's your reference for this algorithm?

Comment: With a [quick glance at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_information_coefficient), looks like you should be doing `I = H_x + H_y - H_{x,y}`, but you're just doing `H_x - H_{x,y}`, but I'm not sure.